# What methods exist for distributing a semi-live dataset with an R package?

Tags: r, packaging

I am building a package for internal use using [`devtools`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/). I would like to have the package load in data from a file/connection (that differs depending on the date package is built). The data is large-ish so having a onetime cost of parsing and loading the data during package building is preferable.

Currently, I have a data.R file under `R/` that assigns the data to package-level variables, the values are assigned during package installation (or at least that's what appears to be happening). This less than ideal setup mostly works. In order to get all instances of the package to have the same data I have to distribute the data file with the package (currently it's being copied to `inst/` by a helper script before building the package) instead of just having it all be packaged together. There must be a better way.

Such as:

- Generate .rda files during package building (but this requires not running the same code during package install)

  - I can do this with a Makefile but that seems like overkill
  - Can I have R code that is only run during package building and not during install?
- Run R code in `data/`

  - But the data is munged using code in the package in question. I can fix that with `Collate` (I think) but then I have to maintain the order of all of the `.R` files (but with that added complexity I might as well use a Makefile?)
- Build two packages, one with all of the code I want, one with the data.
- Obvious, clever things I've not thought of.

tl;dr: What are some methods for adding a snapshot of dynamically changing data to an R package frozen for deployment?

Comment: building two packages seems to make a lot of sense (there are other packages with separate data packages -- mostly packages with large data sets)

Comment: @BenBolker that's the conclusion I've come to, but are there really any other reasonable methods?

Comment: I don't know, after thinking about it for a bit it seems like a pretty reasonable way to go about it; you get the R infrastructure (lazy loading, documentation, etc.), and you get a decoupling between the function versions and the data versions. I don't know my way around `devtools` that well, but if you were using a custom CRAN-like repository you could easily do some package versioning and include wrapper functions in the 'functions' to allow users to install appropriate versions of the 'data' package ...

Comment: @BenBolker shall I leave this question open for a while to see if there are other suggestions?

Comment: don't know.  You could go ahead and post an answer based on whatever conclusions you've come to (to save people the trouble of reading the comments), or you could just leave it unanswered.  I certainly don't see any reason to **close** the question (which would only be appropriate if it were off-topic, "not a real question", too localized, etc.).  (Posting an answer would attract a little bit more attention to the question, which might inspire other ideas.)

Comment: Have you tried putting the code that creates the .rda inside of a Sweave (`*.Snw`) file code block (`<<>>= your-code-here @`)? Seems like that would get run during package building but not install, and should also be run after the rest of the functions in the package have been compiled/loaded. (Not sure whether this would pass `R CMD check`.)

Comment: @Tyler, are you willing to post some sort of synthetic answer just so I don't have to throw the bounty away ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker I'll do that, I was hoping I wouldn't have to accept my own answer (and your bounty). Does the bounty not revert once the time has run out?

Comment: The bounty evaporates if it's not awarded ...  There's a 24-hour grace period, but as I might forget and it's rather unlikely that we'll get a great new answer popping up, I'm going to go ahead and award it now ...

Answer (score 2):

As @BenBolker [points out in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074627/what-methods-exist-for-distributing-a-semi-live-dataset-with-an-r-package#comment19519889_14074627), splitting the dataset out into a different package has precedent in the community (most notably the core package `datasets`) and has additional benefits.

The separation of functions from data also makes working on historic versions of the data easier to do with the up to date functions.

I currently have an `tools-to-munge` package and a `things-to-munge` package. Using a helper script I can build the `tools-to-munge` and setup a `Suggests` (or `Depends`) in the `DESCRIPTION` of both packages to point to the appropriate incrementing version of the packages. After the new `tools-to-munge` package has been built I can build the `things-to-munge` package as necessary using the functions in the `tools-to-munge` package.